# 3D/2.5D TiledMap rendering using gdx

Tags: android, libgdx, openstreetmap, indoor-positioning-system

I am trying to implement a 3D/2.5D map rendering engine, for an indoor navigation android app, so it's should be very flexible according to different hardware configurations,

Currently i am using libgdx for this purpose, and using osm(OpenStreetMap) format as my data model.

it would be appreciate if someone with similar experience, give me some details about the design pattern and procedure of implementing such map rendering engine. Is there any better alternatives instead of libgdx?

Also i wonder to can i use TiledMapRender class to render 3D/2.5D map elements?

Comment: TiledMaps are per default 2D. Take a look at this: http://sertaogames.com/2013/01/30/isometric-tilesets-from-3d-modeling/ .

Comment: You may be interested in taking a look at the (outdoor) [opensciencemap](https://github.com/opensciencemap/vtm) project which uses vector tiles derived from osm.  It renders various map features and 3D buildings.

Comment: @headuck nothing to do with the question